# php script, modify write to file for JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have a php script that is mostly running properly. In fact, the queries are great, but my only issue at this point lies in the JSON portion.

At the end of my script below, I have a loop that treats my `$data` statement as an array and writes that to a JSON file but this is now a problem for me for a few reasons.

1. the data needs to be coming from multiple tables now, and not just from the select statement
2. I need the JSON format to be slightly changed, with examples below.

Currently, the content array and the while loop are simply pulling in data elements, `$d`, from that select statement and then writing the array to the json file. However, I now have `$stmt2` which updates my table with an ID from another table so it's not included in the select statement and I need it to be in the JSON file. I don't know how I would do this, if I could even use another loop.

Another option I though of, was having this script run all of the queries, and once complete, just dump the table `jfi.ambitionphone` to a JSON file, possibly constraining it to just the records for today's date.

The other minor issue is that the JSON currently being written is formatted like this:

```
    {
        "0": {
            "extension": "7200",
            "Total_Talk_Time_seconds": "62",
            "Total_Talk_Time_minutes": "1.03",
            "Total_Outbound": "0",
            "Total_Inbound": "0",
            "Total_Missed": "1",
            "Total_Calls": "1",
            "Time_of_report": "2017-09-05 09:55:54",
            "Date_of_report": "2017-09-05"
        },  ......
```

When I need it like this:

```
    [
      {
        "ExtID" : 75,
        "Extension" : 7218,
        "Total_Talk_Time_seconds" : 1495,
        "Total_Talk_Time_minutes" : 24.92,
        "Total_Inbound" : 10,
        "Total_Outbound" : 1,
        "Missed_Calls" : 4,
        "Total_Calls" : 11,
        "Date_of_report" : "2017-08-15",
        "Time_of_report" : "2017-08-15 16:13:30"
      },  .......
```

So, the main issue currently is that I need my JSON file to include what is already being written in the loop below, but I now need to add (after 'extension') ExtID from `$stmt2`

Here is the script itself:

```
 <?php 
    $data = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT c.extension
                   , sum(Duration) AS Total_Talk_Time_seconds
                   , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
                   , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
                   , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) AS Total_Inbound
                   , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
                   , SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound
                     SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound
                     SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1))  AS Total_Calls
                   , NOW() AS Time_of_report
                   , curdate() AS Date_of_report
               FROM cdrdb.session a
               INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
                    ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
               INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
                    ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
               WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
               AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
               group by c.extension")  or die(mysqli_error( $conn));


      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "Insert into jfi.ambitionphone(Extension,       Total_Talk_Time_seconds, Total_Talk_Time_minutes, Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound,
      Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Date_of_report,Time_of_report )
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
              ON duplicate key update
                  Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds),
                  Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes),
                  Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound),
                  Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound),
                  Missed_Calls = values(Missed_Calls),
                  Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls),
                  Time_of_report = NOW()
                  ") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));

       $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "UPDATE jfi.ambitionphone a,
                                (SELECT * FROM jackson_id.users where id in

 (48,75,76,77,81,82,83,85,86,87,99341,99344,99409,99422,99428)) j
                                SET a.ExtID = j.id where a.extension = j.extension") or die(mysqli_error($conn2));

    echo print_r($stmt);

    // Create the main array
    $content = [];

    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iidiiiiss", $d['extension'],
           $d['Total_Talk_Time_seconds'], $d['Total_Talk_Time_minutes'],
           $d['Total_Outbound'], $d['Total_Inbound'], $d['Total_Missed'], $d['Total_Calls'],
           $d['Time_of_report'], $d['Date_of_report']) ;
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));

      // Store the current row
      $content[] = $d;

    }

          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));


    // Store it all
    file_put_contents('ambitionLog.json', json_encode($content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));

              ?>
```

Comment: $stmt2 doesn't output anything (it's an UPDATE query), so it's not clear how you would expect to use its output anywhere. Maybe you need another SELECT query in order to extract the extra value(s) that you're after.

Comment: It updates the same table, jfi.ambitionphone, with ```ExtID``` and I need that value. So maybe after that executes, I would have to run another select statement in order to pull that value from the table. But does that mean I'd need to select all from  jfi.ambitionphone and build the array from that instead?

Comment: Also since $stmt2 has no parameters, it seems pointless to execute exactly the same query multiple times (which you do because it's executed inside your while loop). Why not just wait until the end and execute it then?

Comment: "It updates the same table, jfi.ambitionphone, with ExtID and I need that value". Well it could well update multiple rows with a different ExtID, depending on the result of the subquery. Which one(s) do you want?

Comment: You're right, I have moved it out of the loop. But to your second question, Yes it does update each row with a different ID, so that's why I'm thinking now that I would need to run a new select after the update that pulls all rows from today and then update my array block to use the new statement. But yes, I would want all. I'm building this JSON file for 15 different agents/records

Comment: that sounds about right. You'd just need to find the right elements in the array and insert the extra values into them, or add new elements if that's what you need. It's not clear exactly what structure you're after, but you're on the right track now I think.

Comment: Ok, I think I see that now. I appreciate the help on that. Also, do you know of anyway I can change the JSON formatting to match my desired format (similar to if exported from MySQL workbench)? I'm trying to get rid of that index number before each set of data but I'm also wondering if I can modify the name of each record within the file, or if I can choose a different name then what it pulls from the sql table?

Comment: I imagine removing JSON_FORCE_OBJECT from the json_encode options would help. Your current output looks like a JSON object, whereas you seem to want an array. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: Ah, perfect. I'll give that a shot and go from there. Thanks for all of the clarification!